# Rounded UIBarButtonItems

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I need to make UIBarButtonItem rounded. In xib even though the style attibute specified as bordered it displays a rectangular shape. Is there any work around to achieve this?

Regards,

Dilshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView` where the customView is a custom UIButton with a round image.